# How to pass a prop to all styled component css properties at once?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Instead of repeatedly picking the prop like this...

```js
const BubbleContainer = styled.View`
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => (theme.debug ? 'white' : 'blue')};
  border-width: ${({ theme }) => (theme.debug ? '1px' : '0px')};
  color: ${({ theme }) => (theme.debug ? 'red' : 'black')};
`;
```

I'd like to do it once like this (*pseudo code*)...

```js
const BubbleContainer = styled.View`
  ${({ theme }) =>
    background-color: {theme.debug ? 'white' : 'blue'};
    border-width: {theme.debug ? '1px' : '0px'};
    color: {theme.debug ? 'red' : 'black'};
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. You just need to use a backtick string for interpolation and multiline support.

```
const BubbleContainer = styled.View`
  ${({ theme }) => `
    background-color: ${theme.debug ? 'white' : 'blue'};
    border-width: ${theme.debug ? '1px' : '0px'};
    color: ${theme.debug ? 'red' : 'black'};
  `}
`;
```

There are a lot of options, this may be a little more legible:

```
const BubbleContainer = styled.View`
  background-color: blue;
  border-width: 0px;
  color: black;

  ${({ theme }) => theme.debug && `
    background-color: white;
    border-width: 1px;
    color: red;
  `}
`;
```

Comment: Yes!! Thanks! Your second approach is exactly what I was looking for. 